# Storing database in PHP sessions

Tags: php, database, session

I have a project based on PHP OOP and I want to know is it very bad to store a database object in `$_SESSION`? It would be very convenient for me as I don't want to write something like

```
<?php 
$db = new Db();
?>
```

in every class, or when I using ajax requests, but just (for example):

```
echo $_SESSION['_db']->queryFirstCell("select count(*) from accounts");
```

It should be like `Zend_Registry`, but without Zend. Please help, maybe I should change my mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot store database object in session, it will not work, you can use persistent connections instead, but in code you will still create new connection (it will be taken from connection pool)

Comment: $_SESSION['_db'] = $page->getDb();
echo $_SESSION['_db']->queryFirstCell("select count(*) from files"); 
but it works for me? I set my Db->_connection once, when constructs database class and dont write nothing like 
mysql_close(Db->_connection)

Comment: @user3907196 `$_SESSION['_db'] = $page->getDb();` creates connection every time you load page

Answer (score 0):

You can change your db method to static so that you won't need to instantiate it all the time!

```
    DB::connect()->query("SELECT * FROM users");
```

Comment: `DB::connect()` will do `new Db()` internally, so what's the difference?